# Efecto Blur/Desenfoque en Windows Forms ¿Es posible?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Desde hace algún tiempo he estado buscando la manera de aplicar un efecto Blur en los Windows Forms de Visual Studio y Windows en general, con esto me refiero a que el `BackColor` del formulario tome lo que tenga detrás de él, pero con una capa de desenfoque semi-transparente encima. Hasta el momento no encontrado nada que me sea útil o se acerque a mi idea.

[image]

Algo así deseo el efecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradezco las respuestas.

Pero ya encontré un método muy funcional, el cual consiste en usar una librería `.dll` que se llama **ExtendAero** para que se extienda el Aero de Windows 7 de la barra de título a todo el formulario. En dado caso de que se cuente con Windows 8, 8.1 o 10 es necesario instalar **Aeroglass** dependiendo de la versión que se disponga: [Descarga](https://www.glass8.eu/download). También necesitaremos una GUI para manipular las configuraciones de este.

En Visual Studio es necesario agregar una nueva librería en los controles, la cual se llama **ExtendAero**. Este se debe agregar al formulario, anclado de los 4 lados y al fondo de todos los controles. Este nuevo control hará que todos los controles que tengan la propiedad `backcolor` en `black` utilizarán el **aero** de Windows. En el ejemplo de abajo, se ha aplicado en el `TextBox`, en el `label` y en el `button`. Esto sólo funciona si se dispone del efecto **Aero**, de lo contrario, el fondo será blanco.

En cuanto a las fuentes originales del archivo `.dll` de **ExtendAero** y la GUI para poder llevar a cabo esto, las he perdido debido al paso del tiempo. Sin embargo, todo lo subí a un archivo .zip en MEGA: [Descarga](https://mega.nz/#!HhNHQa7Q!G55M_PSKmoYV8B7ek5_bnAIygvPNcgcbY9hKK7awZzc) (No sé si eso está permitido, en caso de que no lo esté, háganme saber y lo quitaré)

Para más detalles, pueden consultar [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9c7e99dz-8&feature=youtu.be) que lo explica todo

Acá les dejo cómo me quedo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La explicacion de como se hace no debe ir solamente en un enlace externo, debe estar aca y solo poner el enlace como referencia.

Comment: Añadiré una explicación más amplia, pero no puedo entrar en detalles demasiado grandes, ya que el proceso el algo largo y no sé si quepa en una respuesta.

Comment: El AeroGlass es completamente gratuito, incluso dejé el enlace a la web oficial para su descarga. La GUI para manipularlo, también era gratuita, al igual que el .dll. Nada de ese archivo es pirateado.

Comment: En cuanto al tipo de licencia, lo desconozco completamente. Aunque sí estoy seguro que no es pirata. Si el hecho de que desconozca la licencia del contenido es un motivo para eliminar el enlace, favor de hacérmelo saber y lo quitaré.

Answer (score 0):

El formulario tiene una propiedad `Opacity` que acepta un valor entre 0 (formulario transparente) y 1 (valor por defecto).

No tienes más que cambiar el valor de esta propiedad para hacer el formulario más o menos transparente:

```
Public Sub HacerSemiTransparente()
  miFormulario.Opacity = 0.5
End Sub
```

Comment: Pues ya anteriormente había probado con esa propiedad, pero... afecta a todo el formulario, y yo lo que busco es que afecte únicamente al fondo. También probé con el transparencyKey, pero se aleja a mi idea.

Comment: Pero en el ejemplo que pones formulario y controles tienen transparencia. ¿Quieres hacer un formulario con fondo semitransparente pero con etiquetas y controles con colores sólidos? No tengo claro que el efecto fuese a quedar demasiado bien...